# Bootstrap - Centrar elementos

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy trabajando con bootstrap y requiero centrar una imagen, e intentado con diferentes clases pero no consigo resultado exitoso

alguien sabe alguna solución?

Adjunto mi código html y adjunto el resultado final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/Estilos.css">
  <title>Login Tienda</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="center-block">
   <img src="Imagenes/Campos.jpg">
  </div>




  </body>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: puedes probar con class="text-center" en tu div

Answer (score 2):

Estas usando la clase incorrecta, para centrar elementos tipo bloque [existe la clase](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering) 
`mx-auto`

Ademas de que requieres de los demás elementos estructurales básicos de bootstrap [contenedores](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/) `<div class="container"></div>` y [su sistema de rejillas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)`<div class="row"></div>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Login Tienda</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto">
         <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Boostrap_logo.svg/250px-Boostrap_logo.svg.png">
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente con flexbox;

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center alig-items-center">
 <img src="Imagenes/Campos.jpg">
```

Con esto centras la imagen tanto arriba como a los lados, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por las explicaciones

Finalmente solucioné mi problema de la siguiente forma:

agregue a mi código las clases

"container"
"row"

remplacé la clase center-block por la clase mx-auto

y en un archivo css agregue el siguiente código

```css
.mx-auto {
  display: flex;  /*display: flex; el cual vuelve al contenedor un elemento flex*/
  
  align-items: center;  /*justify-content: center; le decimos a los elementos del contenedor flex que se ubiquen al centro del eje principal eje horizontal*/
  
  justify-content: center; /*align-items: center; estamos diciendo que queremos que los elementos dentro del contenedor flex se ubiquen en el centro del eje secundario eje vertical*/
  
  min-height: 100vh;  /*min-height: 100vh; que significa tome como altura mínima del contenedor el total del alto de la ventana del navegador web utilizado.*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="mx-auto">
     <img src="Imagenes/Campos.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image: Resultado Final!!]